# Keyboard in Android is pushing up my footer TextView. Issue is with middle ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, keyboard, textview, scrollview

I have a layout with a ScrollView in the middle and a TextView in the footer

I need my footer TextView to stay at the bottom when the keyboard opens. Also the Scrollview still needs to scroll when the keyboard is open.

I know there are other questions relating to this but I cannot accurately show the issue in the comments.

I have the following:

Constraint View
   Button (aligned top)
   Scroll View (middle)
   TextView (bottom)

The keyboard pushes my TextView up. Some of the solutions nearly work but they stop the Scrollview from working when the keyboard is open.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open the manifest and add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the activity.

Comment: With this my ScrollView then does not work whilst the keyboard is displayed.